# Best practices обраотки ошибок в spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, архитектура

У меня вопрос по поводу того, как обычно выстраивают архитектуру обработки исключений в RESTful API на Spring Boot.

Я делаю API для чата, и у пользователей есть возможность создавать чаты.

В контроллере `ChatController` есть метод `create`, который принимает запрос и передаёт данные вроде имени чата и его описания в метод `create` сервиса `ChatService`, в котором будет выполняться вся логика.

Чтобы узнать, имеет ли пользователь права на создание чатов, должна быть выполнена проверка, есть ли в списке ролей пользователя `User` хотя-бы одна роль `Role`, которой разрешено совершать действие `Action` с именем name = "CREATE_CHAT"

Для этого из базы данных нужно получить сущность `Action` с соответствующим именем, поэтому сервис вызывает метод `findByName` сервиса `ActionService`, а вот код этого сервиса:

```
public Action findByName(String name) {
        return actionRepository.findByName(name).orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException("Action with name " + name + " was not found.")
        );
    }
```

В итоге `ControllerAdvice` отловит это исключение и в теле ответа в поле message укажет именно сообщение об ошибке, в котором написано, что Action с таким-то именем не найден, хотя я хотел бы, чтобы в ответе отправилось, например, такое сообщение: "Internal server error: cannot verify if you are allowed to create chats.", а засунуть это сообщение в метод `ActionService.findByName` я не могу, потому что этот метод используется далеко не только тогда, когда нужно создать новый чат.

Как поступают в таких случаях? Очевидное решение - каждый раз отлавливать исключение при любом вызове `ActionService.findByName`, после чего выбрасывать новое исключение, дополняя его информативным сообщением и в качестве cause передавая пойманное исключение из `findByName`

Но таких случаев в проекте может быть куча, и если засовывать каждое такое исключение try-catch, то будет намного больше кода. Но в то же время хотелось бы возвращать пользователям понятные сообщения.

Может есть какой-нибудь волшебный способ сделать всё хорошо и при этом коротко?

Comment: Используйте ControllerAdvice, ловите там исключения и кидайтесь оттуда какими хотите ответами. Дополнительно почитать можно тут - https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @wigravy в том-то и дело, что один и тот же метод findByName класса ActionService может вызываться в десяти разных местах, а в ControllerAdvice все эти десять разных случаев будут обрабатываться одинаково и будут иметь одинаковое сообщение об ошибке

Comment: То что `Action` с именем `CREATE_CHAT` не существует в репозитории, это нормальное явление? Если его там нет, то что может сделать клиент? Он его может создать как-то? Или то, что его там нет, это ошибка программиста или ошибка конфигурации системы и единственное, что может сделать пользователь это обратиться в службу поддержки? Если пользователь ничего сделать не может, чтоб исправить проблему, то и детали исключения и ошибки не имеют особого значения для пользователя. Или все же это допустимое явление с точки зрения логики работы API?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Конкретно с этим случаем согласен: в случае, если этого `Action` нет, то это уже неправильная конфигурация базы данных, для этого потом допишу какой-нибудь DbInitializer, но могут быть и случаи, полностью аналогичные этому, например, если пользователь хочет отредактировать какое-то сообщение, а в базе данных такого нет. Тогда это ошибка клиента будет и нужно будет ему понятное сообщение кинуть.
Кстати, вариант @tequillaz мне кажется наиболее подходящим решением

Comment: Не согласен, что это аналогичная ситуация, разница принципиальная. Во-первых, вряд ли в этом случае у вас будет обращение к сообщению пользователя много раз. Во-вторых, в этом случае сообщение, которое в исключении придет из репозитория, типа "сообщение не найдено" будет абсолютно адекватным. Ну и в-третьих, если это будет допустимая ситуация, то у вас будет логика, чтоб ее обрабатывать в любом случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оборачивание в try-catch по каждому месту вызова действительно выглядит плохой идеей, но какую-то обработку по месту вызова `ActionService` делать необходимо. Для таких случаев очень хорошо подходит использование Optional, т.е. нужно не бросать исключения `EntityNotFoundException` в `ActionService` вообще, а обрабатывать ошибки и генерировать специальные исключения сразу по месту их возникновения. Например, код может выглядеть как-то так

```java
    // ...
    @Service
    public class ActionService {
        // ...
        public Optional<Action> findByName(String name) {
            return actionRepository.findByName(name);
        }
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    @RestController
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ChatController {
        private final ActionService actionService
        // ...
        @PostMapping
        public void create(String name) {
            Action action = actionService
                                .findByName(name)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new /*...*/); // Специальное исключение
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
```